# OsmAnd Map black screen

Tags: java, android, osmand

I have three activities, in all the activities below map view of OsmAnd is loaded.

```
<com.data.net.osmand.plus.views.MapViewWithLayers
                android:id="@+id/map_view_with_layers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

When the first activity loaded it worked fine. The map is shown and the lat long is set.
Loading the second activity from the first activity will load the map.
Loading the third activity from the second activity will load the map.

But when I return from the third activity, the second activity map was black screen.
When I got back from the second activity, in the first activity map was a black screen

Please help me with this.

```
OsmandApplication app = (OsmandApplication) getApplication();
mapTileView = app.getOsmandMap().getMapView();
mapTileView.setupRenderingView();
mapTileView.setIntZoom(18);
mapTileView.setLatLon(mLatitude, mLongitude);
```